MLKit Document Scanner Error when scanning
When I run the MLKit DOcument scanner on my Android device, I got an error after configuring the pages limit and press the scan buton. The error is
failed to scan: feature not available in the current version of the google play services
I checked Android API level, minSdkVersion and Device RAM. those are compatible with the required version

can you post some code here please? Otherwise there's not much anyone can do here.

Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

It appears that this is from inadequate version of Google Play Services on the device: https://github.com/googlesamples/mlkit/issues/846
